# When to use Activity workers Vs callback pattern in aws step functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-step-functions

When should I use Activity workers Vs when should I use task tokens in aws step functions?
I know they both help in dealing with asynchronous tasks in step functions. What are their differences, pros, cons and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401041/2442804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

major differences are explained nicely in the link posted by @luk2302, other than that, Activity worker needs to be compute managed by the customer whereas task token/callback pattern is through integrated AWS services which are serverless.